# Belkin AC1200 Router - not resolving DNS requests

Tags: router, dns

In setting up a Belkin AC1200 Modem Router for a family member, I've noticed a weird problem. It connects to the ISP fine and gets their DNS servers etc. However, no device connected to it can resolve DNS addresses. If I manually set the DNS servers on the device, they work fine.

It seems last year, [Belkin had an issue](http://www.reddit.com/r/technology/comments/2ik43h/belkin_firmware_update_1072014_crashing_many/) with symptoms similar to what I'm experiencing. I've tried forcing the router to use Google DNS and OpenDNS and get the same thing. I'd thought it could be the website filtering service, but have made sure that's switched off.

The device is a Belkin AC1200 Modem Router (model F9J1106 v4) connected to a Sky (UK) ADSL connection. According to the dashboard, it's running the latest firmware.

Has anyone experienced the same issue? Any points on how to resolve it?

Comment: Clients connecting to the router get their DNS server ip from the routers DHCP. If You enter the routers DHCP settings, there should be an option to manually change the DNS server. Is it set correctly?

Comment: Belkin routers are notorious for countless mysterious bugs. I would recommend replacing the router with something else, be it a Linksys, Cisco, or even TP-Link.

Comment: There is no option in the DHCP range settings to specify the DNS servers for the clients (there is a search domain, which is blank). There is a general DNS servers section under the ISP details, but I've tried OpenDNS, Google DNS and the ISPs to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have specified a Local Domain Name on the LAN settings of the router. This field is marked as "optional" but I found that when it is blank the router can't start it's own DNS forwarder.